"brew install emacs" vs. "brew --cask install emacs"?
Since owning a MacBook Pro, I have used the homebrew cask of GNU Emacs (i.e., "Emacs for MacOS X"), which according to their web site, is plain GNU Emacs without any particular changes.
Recently I noticed that homebrew includes an GNU Emacs formula in addition to the flask. Checking its build definition, it does seem to be somewhat different, but eventually also just building from source.
Does anyone know if there is a noticeable difference, in practice, between these two installations? They provide the same upstream version.

The formula version of Emacs, provided by Homebrew does not include the GUI. The cask version does.
Here are the configuration options from the two different version (formula vs. cask):
$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-arm64-11 -nw --batch -Q --eval '(print system-configuration-options)'

"--with-ns '--enable-locallisppath=/Library/Application Support/Emacs/${version}/site-lisp:/Library/Application Support/Emacs/site-lisp' --with-modules 'CFLAGS=-DFD_SETSIZE=10000 -DDARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT' --with-x-toolkit=no"

$ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs/29.3/bin/emacs -nw --batch -Q --eval '(print system-configuration-options)'

"--disable-silent-rules --enable-locallisppath=/opt/homebrew/share/emacs/site-lisp --infodir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs/29.3/share/info/emacs --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs/29.3 --with-gnutls --without-x --with-xml2 --without-dbus --with-modules --without-ns --without-imagemagick --without-selinux --with-tree-sitter"

You'll notice that the second one (the formula version) was built with the --without-ns flag, disabling the macOS GUI.

Good find. Little typo? You'll notice that the second one (the cask version) -> I believe you meant "the formula version" here.

@AnoE thanks. fixed.
